# Extjs3 Charts with a dynamic store

Tags: charts, store, extjs3

I'm using this ExtJS 3.4 charts exemple: http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/examples/chart/charts.html (the third one)
I wanna use a store that return values from php instead of a static store like in this exemple.
I hope that my question is clear and thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You are way to unprecise. What PHP-Framework do you want to use? From where are you loading the data?

Depending on your Framework you will need to use different solutions. For plain PHP there are examples provided by Sencha. For CakePHP you want to take a look into http://banchaproject.org, for Symfony there is http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/dsExtDirectPlugin, ....

Also use ExtJS 4!